# Why is "this" in JavaScript said to be an implicit parameter?

Tags: javascript

I wonder why in the book [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja by John Resig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398869X), p. 48, it is said that:

> Whenever a function is invoked, ... an implicit parameter named `this`
>   is also passed to the function.

I was a little puzzled because previously, I read that `this` is actually a keyword.  And maybe it doesn't really matter, except if we try

```
function f() {
    this = {};
}

f();
```

then either Chrome or Node.js will raise an error that it is a invalid left side in assignment.  So if `this` is actually an implicit parameter, then that line shouldn't raise an error?  So I wonder is it true that the book has this mistake about `this` and it should be otherwise?

(**Update:** I also re-checked JavaScript: the Definitive Guide 6th Edition and ECMA-262 and both of them say `this` is a keyword)...

Comment: I don't see controversy here. Can't `this` be a keyword *and* an implicit parameter at the same time? You know, since it's implicit, it requires some way to refer to itself. A keyword, for example.

Comment: so why can't we set it?

Comment: Because you can't set `this` manually. Being a parameter doesn't mean that it could be modified.

Comment: Because that would cause all kinds of confusing side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed an implicit argument, because if you write:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() {
        console.log(this);  // Will be foo.
    }
};

foo.bar();
```

`this` is implicitly bound to `foo` inside `bar()`, as if you had explicitly written:

```
foo.bar.call(foo);
```

Comment: but can't it be actually a keyword?  (I added Update: I also re-checked JavaScript: the Definitive Guide 6th Edition and ECMA-262 and both of them say `this` is a keyword)

Comment: Yes, the `this` token is a language keyword (you cannot define a symbol named `this` in your code). That keyword, in turn, is used to represent the implicit "context" argument passed to all functions. Both concepts are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: so maybe a more accurate description is, "an implicit parameter is passed to the function as the 'function context', and the only way to be able to access this implicit parameter is by using the `this` keyword"?

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(explicitVar /*, this */ ) {
}

// this will only be defined when foo is called
// default: this == window

// directly invoking a function will bind this to `window`
foo(1 /*, window */) // explicitVar == 1, this == window (inside foo)

var a = {
    fuu: foo
}

// invoking foo ON another object binds this to that object
a.fuu(2 /*, a */) // explicitVar == 2, this == a (inside a.fuu)

// even when you reuse a function that was assigned to another object,
// the this will only be bound when invoking
bar = a.fuu
bar(3 /*, window */) // explicitVar == 3, this == window (inside bar)
```

From these examples you can see that, to explain `this`, you can either describe it as a magic keyword with special execution semantics, or you could explain it as implicit parameter since it gets only assigned when invoking the function in some context.

Answer (score 0):

It's both!

It's an implicit parameter, because it's not part of the function declaration, e.g.

```
function foo()
{
    // this === window
}

foo();
```

And yet, it's there just like any other object reference because of the way JavaScript executes `foo()`:

```
foo.call(window)
```

But it's also a keyword in the sense that it's governed by certain rules, such as being unable to assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, these are the 2 dimensions of the same concept.

keyword 'this' => It is for the user to identify strings that shouldn't be used as a function or variable name.

Implicit parameter 'this' => It is a way by which javascript engine identifies that object, which in turn is abstracted by you, by the user something like

```
  this.name //I don't care about which object. It is taken care of
```

rather than confusing yourself with

```
  obj1.name // or is it, obj2 !!! ??
```

Here the 'taking care' part becomes the keyword for a user, and a implicit parameter for the javascript engine so that it can carry the abstraction for you.